# html center div always in the middle, other two dynamic

Tags: html

I want to create simple HTML. I want to create 3 divs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen">
    <title>My Site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="top_left">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="top_center">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="top_right">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

center div is fixed size and always in the middle. but first and third div are dynamics. How to make this.

CSS

```
#top_left {
    background-image: url(images/pikacom_01.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;    
    background-position: left;
    height: 85px;
}

#top_center {
    background-image: url(images/pikacom_02.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;    
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 85px;
}

#top_right {
    background-image: url(images/pikacom_03.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: right; 
}
```

Comment: Can you specify the width and height of `#top_right` and `#top_left` in advance or are these dynamically sized based on content?

Comment: I would assume the height being 85px (see `#top_left`). And since it's called `top_ ...` it's probably some kind of header. As for the width, see my answer, left and right column a truly flexible.

Comment: #top_left and #top_right are dynamic and depend of size of the screen. Center is only 1024 px width...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
.left {float:left;}
.center {width:1024px;margin:0 auto;}
.right {float:right;}
</style>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
```

Comment: thx but this is without images. I have problemms when i am using images

Comment: write the background image width as min-width for relevant element. For ex. if pikacom_01.gif width 50px, write .left {min-width:50px}

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to give left and right column a width of 50%, left or right float and a negative margin to the left or right respectively. The negative margin should be half of your center columns width, hence in your case -512px.

Then add content divs inside left and right column and give them a positive margin of the same value (512px).

That's it, see my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ggc7e/). Note the changed order of html elements (center comes last). Additionally, in demo center div's width is only 300px for illustration.

```
#top_left {
    background: #00f; // background-colors only added for illustration purposes
    background-image: url(images/pikacom_01.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;    
    background-position: left;
    height: 85px;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;
}
#top_left_content {
  margin-left: 512px;
}

#top_center {
    background: #f0f;
    background-image: url(images/pikacom_02.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;    
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 85px;
}

#top_right {
    background: #ff0;
    background-image: url(images/pikacom_03.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: right; 
    height: 85px;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: -512px;
}
#top_right_content {
  margin-right: 512px;
}
```

​

Comment: I don't know the nature of your background images. If alignment is important, you probably have to assign them to the ..._content divs.

Comment: hmm now i have problem with width:50%. Can i use dynamic size? If center is 1024px and screen is 1920px then left and right is not 50%

Comment: That's why there is the negative margin. It subtracts half of your center div from 50%. That way, the left and right column ALWAYS fill the rest of the page regardless of how wide your screen is.